# can't find "allow executing file as program" checkbox

Tags: 12.04, xubuntu, minecraft, executable

I'm currently trying to run a game on xubuntu that is downloaded as a .jar and to make it work I need to check of a box that says "allow executing file as program" I know where the box should be for everyone else but it isn't there for me. I use xubuntu 12.04 and the check box should be under properties> permissions.

Comment: You can do it from a command line with `chmod a+x file` replacing file with with the file name.  Otherwise have you tried right clicking the file and selecting properties.  I don't use Xubuntu so I have a different file manager but right click works in Ubuntu and Lubuntu.  You may need to prefix the command with `sudo` if you don't have write permissions for the file

Comment: Also it is possible that file was downloaded by another user. In this case, the `chown` command can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option, to make a file executable is only shown for programs that the file manager considers to be of an executable file type. Jar-files are not in that list, although on Ubuntu setting them executable allows you to run them (maybe this should be reported as a bug?). Depending on the settings used when compiling the kernel (or generally on other operating systems), setting jar files executable might not work, and I guess this is the reason why file managers don't consider them runnable.

So, your options are:

- Use the command line tool `chmod` to add the execute permission. (`chmod +x <filename>`)
- Don't care about execute permissions and just always run `java -jar <filename>`.

  - You can create a launcher icon that runs this command.
  - You can create a write a wrapper shell script that can then be set executable. Most java programs available in the Ubuntu repositories install such a wrapper to /usr/bin, while the jar files reside in /usr/share/java

Comment: Thank you so much for your help everything I needed worked perfectly.