# How do I mark a file as executable on Xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, executable

I need to know how to mark a file as executable but the check box is not there.

Comment: next time include the system you use ;) Does this help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/321780/cant-find-allow-executing-file-as-program-checkbox ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal.
2. Navigate to the location of your file by inputting `cd` command into the terminal 
   Eg. `cd /documents/`, then enter the following:

   ```
   chmod +x yourfilename
   ```

To view if your changes had been saved enter the following `ls -l` in the terminal.

Other way to change your file to an executable is to right click the file, select **Properties** → **Permisions** and tick **Allow execution of the file as a program**.

Hope this helps. Also to execute the file you first have to be in the directory where it is located. For instance if your file is located in the `Documents` folder, you have to `cd` ("change directory") in to that directory and then do this: `./yourfile.c`

This is how it will look:

```
root@root:~/Documents$ ./file.c
```

Comment: You don't need to CD to the directory of the file to execute it if the directory is on the PATH or if you include the full path when executing like `~/bin/file-to-execute`

Comment: yes I know. But he barely knows how to make the file an executable (no offence). I only answered what he needed to know.

Answer (score 0):

As you say the checkbox is not there, I assume you are in the correct place to change it in Thunar so if the checkbox in Properties -> permissions is not there, it is because the file is not an executable file (if it is a script, did you include `#!/bin/bash` at the beginning?)

If the checkbox is there and you can't change it, it is because you are not alowed to change the file (not owner?).

Comment: I am logged in as the correct user. Also the file I am trying to do this on is a .jar. I am a complete noob at Xubuntu so if I cant quite understand some of the things you say I'm sorry.

Comment: So this is why it can't be marked as executable as jar files are not executables directly. Have a look at this answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/321780/cant-find-allow-executing-file-as-program-checkbox?lq=1